# Listing with capital Letters and negative margin

Tags: css, margin

I am programming the following list which keeps distance between the capital letter and text even if the text is consists of multiple lines. Right now the capital letters and the following texts are not on the same line, especially when viewed with different browsers like Safari mobile or OSX Safari. I think negative margin-top is the problem here. Do you have Ideas to improve this code? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
<style type="text/css">

ul {
list-style: none;
margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

ul li a {
background-color: #F7F7F7;
border: 1px solid #999999;
color: #000000;
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
padding: 12px 12px;
}

ul li:first-child a {
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

ul li:last-child a {
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}


#inside {
margin:-22px 0px 0px 26px; 
}

h1 {
font-size: 20px;
font-weight:bold;
display:inline;
}

</style>

<ul>
<li><a href="#"><h1>A</h1><div id="inside">Some text</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h1>B</h1><div id="inside">Some text</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h1>C</h1><div id="inside">Some text</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now define your** `h1` tag and `#inside id` `display:inline-block;` or **remove negation margin**   and define your **anchor tag** `line-height` according to your design .

**Used to this css**

```
ul {
list-style: none;
margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

ul li a {
background-color: #F7F7F7;
border: 1px solid #999999;
color: #000000;
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 12px;
    line-height:16px; // add this line
    border-bottom:0; // add this line
}

ul li:first-child a {
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

ul li:last-child a {
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; // add this line
}


h1, #inside {
margin:0; // add this line
    display:inline-block; // add this line
    vertical-align:top; // add this line
}

h1 {
font-size: 20px;
font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:5px; // add this line
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mNaVY/)***

Comment: ok, thank you. But now if the text is over multiple lines it wont keep distance to the capital letter.